# Calling predicate at the begining of the run

Tags: prolog

I need to check call a predicate automatically at the consult or start of pl.
Is there a such code to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives are executed during source consult. Then when Prolog load a file in which appear (for instance)

```
...
:- writeln(hello).
:- writeln(world).
...
```

will write the message.

A special directive is [initialization](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28initialization%29/1)/1:

> Call Goal after loading the source file in which this directive appears has been completed.

Comment: Arbitrary queries used as directives should be avoided. Using the ISO Prolog standard directive initialization/1 is indeed the advised solution.

Comment: actually i cannot understand usage of initialization can you give me an example code of it. for example have can call predicate abc for every consult..

Comment: Just add the line ":- initialization(abc)." to your source file.